# Creating an iterator of subsequences from an iterator of items

Tags: scala, functional-programming, iterator

If I have a `Seq`, then it is easy to generate all the subsequences up to a given length limit, as follows:

```
def subseqs[A](n: Int)(s: Seq[A]) = {
  (1 to n).flatMap(s.sliding)
}                                            

subseqs(3)(List(1, 2, 3, 4)) foreach println    //> List(1)
                                                //| List(2)
                                                //| List(3)
                                                //| List(4)
                                                //| List(1, 2)
                                                //| List(2, 3)
                                                //| List(3, 4)
                                                //| List(1, 2, 3)
                                                //| List(2, 3, 4)
```

However, is there an idiomatic (**and reasonably efficient**) way to do the same with an iterator as input, producing an iterator (or perhaps a Stream) as output?

**Updated:** I have a [working implementation](https://gist.github.com/davidallsopp/9764705) that implements Iterator, and does this in a single pass, so needs very little memory, but is relatively long and uses mutable variables (`var` and `ListBuffer`) - can post this if it would help. I am hoping there is a more elegant way using higher-order functions...

The approach above (using `sliding()`) won't work because the iterator is exhausted by the first pass, and cannot be re-used.

Using a combination of `sliding()` and `inits()` is better, but misses off the tail-end of the expected subsequences:

```
def subseqsi[A](n: Int)(i: Iterator[A]) = {
  //(1 to n).flatMap(i.sliding) 
  // no - this exhausts the iterator

  i.sliding(n).flatMap { _.inits.filterNot(_.isEmpty) } 
  //nearly, this misses off subsequences towards the end
} 
                                              //> List(1, 2, 3)
                                              //| List(1, 2)
                                              //| List(1)
                                              //| List(2, 3, 4)
                                              //| List(2, 3)
                                              //| List(2)
```

My input data is an Iterator of unknown (potentially very large) size. The order of the output subsequences does not matter.

Comment: This is a golfy one I used to write in Haskell back in the day. I'll give the Haskell code and leave translating it to Scala up to the reader :) `init . tails <=< tail . inits` works on both finite and infinite lists, so it kind of has to be lazy by construction! The fish/`<=<` operator is from `Control.Monad` and is Kleisli composition.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `Stream`:

```
def subseqs[A](n: Int)(iter: Iterator[A]) = {
  val i = iter.toStream
  1 to n flatMap i.sliding
}
```

A Stream is lazy as an Iterator is, but it stores all the values that are already computed.

Comment: That's nice and elegant, and produces correct output, but eagerly creates an IndexedSeq of `n` Streams, so it behaves badly with large input such as `(1 to 1000000).iterator`. If you add `toStream` to the `(1 to n)` I think it behaves more lazily...?

Comment: `1 to n` is strict, of course. And `toStream` or `iterator` make it lazy, yes.

Comment: OK, `toStream` helps a bit, but unfortunately it is still very expensive on memory as `n` increases (presumably because we end up memoizing the whole sequence?). For `n` up to 1000 or so, the difference is a small factor; for n=1,000,000 I hit a GC wall with my current heap size. Using `iterator` is better; n=1,000,000 is OK, but another factor of 10 makes it struggle once more.

Comment: Of course, when you increase your `n` you need more memory. The stdlib of Scala doesn't support a data structure that automatically cleans up its cache if `n` is too large, you either have to find a library for that or build it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using Streams - much less elegant than the flatMap/sliding approach (which it uses for the final few elements), but much faster and less memory-hungry.

```
def subseqs[A](n: Int)(s: Iterator[A]) = {
  def loop(s: Stream[A], history: Vector[A]): Stream[Seq[A]] = {
    if (s.isEmpty) (1 to n).flatMap(history.sliding).toStream
    else if (history.length == n) 
      history.inits.filterNot(_.isEmpty).toStream #::: loop(s.tail, history.tail :+ s.head)
    else loop(s.tail, history :+ s.head)
  }
  loop(s.toStream, Vector())
}
```

This builds up a history until there are n elements, outputs the `inits`, then shifts the history along. However, not only is the code uglier, it also returns the results in an ugly order, due to the need to handle the end of the stream as a special case:

```
subseqs(3)(List(1, 2, 3, 4)) foreach println  > Vector(1, 2, 3)
                                              | Vector(1, 2)
                                              | Vector(1)
                                              | Vector(2)
                                              | Vector(3)
                                              | Vector(4)
                                              | Vector(2, 3)
                                              | Vector(3, 4)
                                              | Vector(2, 3, 4)
```

I'm still hopeful that an elegant **and** fast solution is possible...

Comment: Did you see my Haskell solution?

Comment: I did, thanks - it looks very cool, but I don't currently know how to translate that into Scala, or how it might perform - obviously Haskell and Scala are rather different in terms of laziness, compilation, etc.